# LinearLayout used as item layout in ListView won't go to the right

Tags: android, listview, alignment, android-linearlayout, nine-patch

I am trying to align to the right some ListView items, but they won't budge from the left hand side. The gravity and layout_gravity attributes don't appear to be working.

This code also aligns the layout to the right in the XML code, but doesn't at run time when populating the ListView.

Here is the XML I am using, which also uses a 9 patch image as the background of the LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_9Patch_image"
    android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="16dp">


    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:gravity="left|bottom"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**I also tried to set the params in my adapter's getView method using:**

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you try to describe what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am building a chat application, for the incoming messages, the messages go on the left, and the sent messages go on the right. Each message layout contains a message and time stamp.  I use two different XML layouts, and inflate the appropriate layout (incoming or outgoing message layout) in the adapter's getView method. Thanks

Comment: no I'm asking about the layout you want to see? you wanna to have a TextView at the left and one aligned to the right. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, I want a LinearLayout as the shape of the chat bubble, then the message text  in the TextView going from left to right in the bubble, and for the outgoing message, to have the TextView which contains the timestamp to be on the bottom left.

Comment: You know about Relative Layouts?

Comment: I tried something similar using the align attributes in a RelativeLayout but it didn't seem to work, I will try it again if I can't get this to work. Would there be any significant advantage to using a RelativeLayout in this situation?

Comment: No, Just a smaller view tree is better. So If you can get it by just a parent and its children is way better than nesting views. I'm talking from the performance perspective.

Comment: I understand that nesting should be avoided, but I haven't found a different solution yet. I tried using a RelativeLayout with these attributes:  **android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
     android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list1"
    android:background="@drawable/9PatchImage"**  but it would still stick to the left at run time. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: If you can paint me the view using any tool and post it here. I'll gladly help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at rowbuttonlayout.xml from http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Basically, you are trying to change the gravity of the items, but you are trying form the outside of the list view. Likely it is trying to adhere by moving the whole list view to the right, but the list view takes up all of the space so you don't even notice it
If you want individual elements to be left justified, you will want to make custom cells that are left justified that are made when you want left justified, or make your own cell, and left justify the stuff in that cell when necessary

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a read and give it a go. But can you clarify what you mean by justified please ?

Comment: In the same aspect that a text document is justified. It's which side the text clings to or if it's centered.

Comment: When I switched on 'show layout bounds' using the dev. opts I could see the ListView rows only took up as much space as the wrapped content in the views not the whole parent. When you say say custom cell, do you mean row ? I did try that, both with a LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. It only worked when I added another parent container. I did look at the link you sent me too, it seems they were aligning the views contained in the parent to the right of left, this does work for me, but the parent container is what is not moving to the right or left, without a wrapper which is the problem.Thanks

Comment: When I say cell, I mean row. I'm confused. I posted this based on the description of your issue when making custom rows you will likely make them as a view with views inside of them. The views inside of the list would have "match_parent" as their width and then have the gravity settings set up so it sticks to its respective side. This will allow the row items to stick to the side of the list view. If you are trying to make the whole list view stick to one side of the screen (and have some space on the other side) you will need a relative view and to cap the width of the list view

Comment: Additionally changing the gravity of the list view will move the list view but, will not affect the gravity of the individual row items in the list view. To affect the gravity of the row items you need to have control over the view of the row item. To do this it's easy to make a custom row view that you use instead of the default row view.

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary solution** (I'll be back). This seems to be inefficient but you can add another LinearLayout to wrap the other LinearLayout. Take the containter LinearLayout and set both the height and width to match_parent, and put the gravity attribute to right. Then add the 9 patch image to the nested LinearLayout instead of having it at the parent container LinearLayout view level, and change the its height and width to wrap_content.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right"
               >

            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/purple_right_2"
            >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_outgoing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="16dp">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/clockView"
        android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```